# Can internet explorer run two different application with different compatibility requirements in two different tabs

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have an application that must be run on IE with compatibility mode turned on for the website. We are building another application, and it will not potentially support compatibility mode. Hence, I would like to will there be any issue in accessing these two applications in different tabs in IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to Tools -> Compatibility view settings.

[image]

You can see that we need to add the site here on the list to open it in compatibility mode.

The site which is added here will only get open in compatibility mode.

Other sites, which are not on the list will get open normally.

So IE browser can handle two different sites that have different compatibility requirements in two different tabs without any issue.